# How to catch the ending resize window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize, window

I need catch the event endresize in WPF.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

WPF doesn't provide an event that solely fires at the end of the resize process. **SizeChanged** is the only event associated with Window resizing - and it will fire multiple times during the resizing process.

A total hack would be to constantly set a timer ticking when the SizeChanged event fires. Then timer will not get a chance to tick until resizing ends and at that point do your one time processing.

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    _resizeTimer.Tick += _resizeTimer_Tick;
}

DispatcherTimer _resizeTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1500), IsEnabled = false };

private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _resizeTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    _resizeTimer.Stop();
    _resizeTimer.Start();
}

void _resizeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _resizeTimer.IsEnabled = false;    

    //Do end of resize processing
}
```

Comment: Form.ResizeBegin/End in Winforms.  The notification is still there, but ignored in WPF.  Two steps forward, one step back.

Comment: @Martin, explain please why u put _resizeTimer.IsEnabled = true; before stop-start? That looks like no sense for me.

Comment: I like this mechanism because it allows doing some processing when user pauses a resize. Had situation where needed to re-layout the canvas when user resized. With this timer approach when user stopped moving the mouse (but not released it) the re-layout can be executed and the affect of the new size can be seen.
My test team liked it rather than the previous - re-layout only occurred when mouse released ie WM_EXITSIZEMOVE approach.

I did set the timer interval to 200ms instead than the 1500 value used in this example code.

Answer (score 16):

Reactive Extensions for .NET provides some really cool capabilities for dealing with standard event patterns including being able to throttle events. I had a similar problem in dealing with size changed events and while the solution is still somewhat "hacky" I think that Reactive Extensions provides a much more elegant way of implementing it. Here is my implementation:

```
IObservable<SizeChangedEventArgs> ObservableSizeChanges = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<SizeChangedEventArgs>(this, "SizeChanged")
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

IDisposable SizeChangedSubscription = ObservableSizeChanges
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(x => {
        Size_Changed(x);
    });
```

This will effectively throttle the `SizeChanged` event such that your Size_Changed method (where you can execute custom code) will not be executed until 200 milliseconds (or however long you would like to wait) have passed without another `SizeChanged` event being fired.

```
private void Size_Changed(SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    // custom code for dealing with end of size changed here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

NO Timer Needed with very clean solution that have given by @Bohoo up, i just adapted his code from vb.net to c#

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
            }

            private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // this two line have to be exactly onload
                HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
                source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
            }


            const int WM_SIZING = 0x214;
            const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x232;
            private static bool WindowWasResized = false;


            private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
            {
                if (msg == WM_SIZING)
                {

                    if (WindowWasResized == false)
                    {

                        //    'indicate the the user is resizing and not moving the window
                        WindowWasResized = true;
                    }
                }

                if (msg == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE)
                {

                    // 'check that this is the end of resize and not move operation          
                    if (WindowWasResized == true)
                    {

                        // your stuff to do 
                        Console.WriteLine("End");

                        // 'set it back to false for the next resize/move
                        WindowWasResized = false;
                    }
                }

                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can detect exactly when a WPF window resize ended, and you don't need a timer. A native window receive the `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` message when the user release the left mouse button at the end of a window resize *or* move operation. A WPF window doesn't receive this message, so we need to hook up a `WndProc` function which will receive it. We can use `HwndSource` with `WindowInteropHelper` to get our window handle. Then we will add the hook to our `WndProc` function. We will do all that in the window `Loaded` event (vb.net code):

```vb
Dim WinSource As HwndSource    

Private Sub WindowLoaded_(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    WinSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(New WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle)
    WinSource.AddHook(New HwndSourceHook(AddressOf WndProc))
End Sub
```

Now, in our `WndProc`, we will listen to the `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` message:

```vb
Const WM_EXITSIZEMOVE As Integer = &H232

Private Function WndProc(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr

    If msg = WM_EXITSIZEMOVE Then

        DoWhatYouNeed()
    End If

    Return IntPtr.Zero
End Function
```

This and a similar technique is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.fromhwnd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf).

Notice that the function should return IntPtr.Zero. Also, don't do in this func anything except handling the specific messages you are interested in.

Now, `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` is also sent at the end of a move operation, and we are interested only in resize. There are several ways to determine that this was the end of resize operation. I did it by listening to the `WM_SIZING` message (which sent many times during resize), combined with a flag. The whole solution looks like this:

(Note: Don't get confused with the code highlighting here, cause its wrong for vb.net)

```vb
Dim WinSource As HwndSource
Const WM_SIZING As Integer = &H214
Const WM_EXITSIZEMOVE As Integer = &H232

Dim WindowWasResized As Boolean = False

Private Sub WindowLoaded_(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    WinSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(New WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle)
    WinSource.AddHook(New HwndSourceHook(AddressOf WndProc))
End Sub

Private Function WndProc(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr

    If msg = WM_SIZING Then

        If WindowWasResized = False Then

            'indicate the the user is resizing and not moving the window
            WindowWasResized = True
        End If
    End If

    If msg = WM_EXITSIZEMOVE Then

        'check that this is the end of resize and not move operation          
        If WindowWasResized = True Then

             DoWhatYouNeed()

             'set it back to false for the next resize/move
             WindowWasResized = False
        End If            
    End If

    Return IntPtr.Zero
End Function
```

That's it.

Comment: We should handle `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` instead of `WM_SIZING`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

For UWP with Rx (System.Reactive)

```
            //Stop window updates
            rootFrame = new Frame
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width,
                Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height
            };

            //updates after throttling
            var sizeChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<WindowSizeChangedEventHandler, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs>(
                      handler => Window.Current.SizeChanged += handler,
                      handler => Window.Current.SizeChanged -= handler);

            sizeChangedObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.35)).ObserveOnDispatcher(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal).Subscribe(x =>
            {
                rootFrame.Width = x.EventArgs.Size.Width;
                rootFrame.Height = x.EventArgs.Size.Height;
            });
```