# WPF equivalent of Form.BeginResize / Form.EndResize

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

In WinForms we had the ability to hook `Form.ResizeBegin` and `Form.ResizeEnd` to be notified when a `Form` was about to begin resizing and after it had finished resizing.

Is there a way to get similar functionality for a WinForms `UserControl` hosted in a `WindowsFormsHost` in WPF?

Comment: Closest thing I found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474670/how-to-catch-the-ending-resize-window

Comment: @DMan - I've implemented something very similar, it works... ok... feels hacky though.  Thanks for the help :)