# WPF end of resizing operation doesn't work with Systems.Timers.Timer class

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to catch the end of a window resizing process using a timer in WPF. First I used a timer from System.Timers, it doens't work an I changed to the solution as stated here (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer):

[How to catch the ending resize window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474670)

Everthing is ok now, but does anybody know the reason of this behavior ? An earlier solution to get the end of a resizing operation used a classic timer from System.Timers namespace. Am I forced to use the DispatcherTimer ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It should work with a regular `System.Timers.Timer` if you explicitly invoke your UI code on the UI thread. `DispatcherTimer`, among other things, just does that for you implicitly.

Comment: The elapsed handler from Systems.Timers.Timer is called from another thread, not the UI thread, that's the reason, invoking the UI thread from here does the job, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing with `System.Timers.Timer`. Note that it has different (but similar) methods and properties than the `DispatcherTimer`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        _resizeTimer.Elapsed += _resizeTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _resizeTimer.Stop();
        _resizeTimer.Start();
    }

    System.Timers.Timer _resizeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 1500 };

    void _resizeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _resizeTimer.Stop();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SizeChanged end");
        //Do end of resize processing

        //you need to use BeginInvoke to access the UI elements
        //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)
    }
}
```

One thing is more important, that `System.Timers.Timer` runs on a different thread other than the UI thread, which means you can't directly manipulate UI elements from within the `_resizeTimer_Elapsed` method. You need to use `BeginInvoke` to marshal the call back to the UI thread.

Find the differences between `System.Timers.Timer` and `DispatcherTimer`. There are many questions and answers on this subject. I just want to show you how to do it with the *classic timer*.