# Windows App SDK WinUI 3 TextBox shaky when resizing window with relative panel

Tags: xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I find that when I place a TextBox control inside a RelatviePanel and align its sides with the panel the text gets jumpy when I resize the height of the window. If I change the property TextWrapping to "NoWrap" then the problem goes away but I want the text to wrap and be able to resize the window without the text jumping up and down ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Window
    x:Class="AcrylicTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AcrylicTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <RelativePanel>
        <TextBox
            Visibility="Visible"
            x:Name="directions"
            TextWrapping= "Wrap" 
            Background="White"
            Foreground="Black"
        
            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"

            >
        </TextBox>

    </RelativePanel>
    

    </Window>
```

Note: This appears to be a bug in the Windows App SDK. I submitted an issue on Github for it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3862). In the meantime the workaround I am using is to hide the text while the window is resizing. Its not ideal but it looks better than the text jumping up and down. There is no event exposed to handle the completion of a window resize so I had to monitor win32 events to accomplish it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872903/1094779) answer on Stack overflow is what I based my code on.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you make sure that the code above is reproducible on a plain WinUI 3 project?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I can reproduce. After inputting some text, the text gets jumpy when I'm increasing the height of the window.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT You are right. It does get jumpy. But I guess this is not because the `TextBox` is inside a `RelativePanel`. This also happens inside a vertical stretched `Grid`. I also tried this with a `GridSplitter` at the bottom of the `TextBox` and got the same jumpy result. So, it seems that this issue happens when the `TextBox`'s height is changed from the bottom side.

Comment: @user1094779 You filed the issue on the WinAppSDK repo. Since this issue is a WinUI 3 issue, you should file it on the [WinUI repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) and delete the one on the WinAppSDK repo.

Comment: Okay, I filed it on the WinAppSDK repo because that was the link the MSFT employee provided me for reporting the issue when I originally asked the question on their forum.