# Catching MouseMove while moving window with DragMove

Tags: wpf, window, move, mousemove

I have a borderless WPF window (WindowStyle="None") that can be moved by catching LeftMouseDown and then call DragMove. That works fine.

However, I want to prevent any part of the window from leaving the screen area.
I catch the LocationChanged but that is called AFTER the window has already moved and thus any changes to the windows position I make in that event cause the window to jump back, which looks very unprofessional.

Is there an event I can catch that is fired BEFORE the window is actually moved.
I tried MouseMove and PreviewMouseMove but they don't get fired during DragMove.

This stuff works fine with WinForms.

Does anybody have a solution for this or is this just due to the half-baked nature and state of WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the CoerceValueCallback approach to work (if anybody has a solution for this approach please share it).

My solution:
Intercept WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message in a WPF WndProc. The solution is a bit long to post here, but here are 2 links that put me on the right track:

[How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)
(There were a few nay-sayers in this link that stated that WndProc would not work with WPF.
I can't comment on the statement in that general fashion but in this particular case it works like a charm.)

http://huddledmasses.org/wpf-windows-that-snap-to-screen-edges/

Put body of OnPreviewPositionChange in WndProc.

Answer (score 0):

> This stuff works fine with WinForms

Yes, but on the other hand, WinForms doesn't have `DragMove`... You could try to do it the same way as in WinForms, by handling `MouseMove` and moving the window yourself.

Another option would be to override the metadata for the `Top` and `Left` dependency properties with a `CoerceValueCallback` to prevent the window from leaving the screen. Not sure if that would work, though...

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I'll look into CoerceValueCallback.