# How do I make my WPF application as activex (out of process)

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, out-of-process

I have a wpf application. I want to make this a activex com component (Out of process), so that from other applications like Excel, VB, etc.. I can call my WPF application as activeX com.

How do I make my wpf application as activeX?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear statements. I have tried the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c/) . But the instance is running within the caller's thread. I want to be a separate process.

Comment: Ah okay, that's not somethings I can help with, I'm mostly C++, but put those details in your question for better help. Make sure to ask a question 

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294297/exposing-wpf-control-as-activex-control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)