# Show WPF window from another application in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, process, window

I have an WPF application called app1 which has a windows named window1. When the user clicks the close button of `window1`, the app does not close but the window1 hides (`this.hide()`).

I want to check if another instance of the application is already running when it is started; if so, I want to show the already running instance and terminate the new one.

How can I do that?

I know how to check the process and how to close the current app but I don't know how to show a window from another WPF process which is running...

In my App startup event I do this :

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if(Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Count() > 1)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do the work!

My problem solved with "Reed Copsey" help and with Windows SendMessage API.
for doing this thing I wrote these codes in my window1.xaml.cs file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;


namespace app1
{
    public partial class window1: Window
    {
        public window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private void window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
        }
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Message m = System.Windows.Forms.Message.Create(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            if (m.Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                // Get the COPYDATASTRUCT struct from lParam.
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));

                // If the size matches
                if (cds.cbData == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)))
                {
                    // Marshal the data from the unmanaged memory block to a 
                    // MyStruct managed struct.
                    MyStruct myStruct = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cds.lpData,
                        typeof(MyStruct));

                    // Display the MyStruct data members.
                    if (myStruct.Message == "Show Up")
                    {
                        this.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        internal const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct MyStruct
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string Message;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;       // Specifies data to be passed
            public int cbData;          // Specifies the data size in bytes
            public IntPtr lpData;       // Pointer to data to be passed
        }


    }
}
```

And I wrote these codes in my App.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace app1
{    
    public partial class App : Application
    {       
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct MyStruct
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string Message;
        }



        internal const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;       // Specifies data to be passed
            public int cbData;          // Specifies the data size in bytes
            public IntPtr lpData;       // Pointer to data to be passed
        }
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        internal class NativeMethod
        {            
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
                IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);


            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Count() > 1)
            {
                IntPtr hTargetWnd = NativeMethod.FindWindow(null, "window1");
                if (hTargetWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                {                    
                    return;
                }
                MyStruct myStruct;
                myStruct.Message = "Show Up";
                int myStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(myStruct);
                IntPtr pMyStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myStructSize);
                try
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(myStruct, pMyStruct, true);

                    COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                    cds.cbData = myStructSize;
                    cds.lpData = pMyStruct;
                    NativeMethod.SendMessage(hTargetWnd, WM_COPYDATA, new IntPtr() , ref cds);

                    int result = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (result != 0)
                    {                       
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMyStruct);
                }
                Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
            }            
        }  

    }
}
```

And that's it. :D

Answer (score 6):

A typical approach to this is to use a Mutex.  This allows you to prevent a second instance from being started (or rather, *detect it within the second instance* of the application).

At that point, you can notify the original application instance to "show" itself.  Here is [a good article describing the entire process in detail](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) (though using Windows Forms).

For a WPF application, you'll need to put this logic in the Application's startup logic, and [add an HwndSourceHook to process the windows message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf) in your WPF window which you want to have show.