# Detect restart in Windows 8 - SessionEnding not called

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, shutdown

When the user shuts downs Windows 8 [from the Settings charm](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/charms-tutorial), my WPF application can detect that with the SessionEnding event.

[image: Power under charms]

In the case of choosing *Shut down*, I get "Session Ending Due To SystemShutdown"

```
SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;

private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{            
    Trace.WriteLine("Session Ending Due To " + e.Reason);           
}
```

### *Shut down* calls SessionEnding, but *Restart* does not

But when the user chooses *Restart* then SessionEnding is not called!

### Detecting *Restart* intent in Windows 8

- How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here they say that by watching for WM_EndSession message you should be able to watch for a reboot: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/94616-detect-windows-shutdownlogoffrestart-event/

You will also need to hook to WndProc in your WPF application : [How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)

Comment: I was now able to catch normal restart in the SessionEnding event as well, not sure what has changed in my code..

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it !