# Native SendMessage with WndProc Override for IPC not working

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, native, wndproc

I have a WPF application that is started with no parameters or flags.  In the `App.xaml.cs` I added an `OnStartUp` handler that attempts to do some IPC to another instance of the application IF it executed with parameters.  For example, my main application might be started by simply executing `mainApp`, which would load the main windows.  Then I might later execute `mainApp msg bob some_message` which would pass the condition in `OnStartUp` and send "msg bob some_message" to the up and running application to handle in its `WndProc` override.

Code in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void OnStartUp(object sedner, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   Process localProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

   foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(localProcess.ProcessName))
   {
      if (process.Id != localProcess.Id)
      {
         NativeMethods.SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, NativeMethods.HWND_IPC, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
         Environment.Exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Code in main window codebehind:

```
public IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr iParam, ref bool handled)
{
   if (msg == NativeMethods.HWND_IPC)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Message Received!");
   }

   return IntPtr.Zero;
}

internal class NativeMethods
{
   public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
   public const int HWND_IPC = 0xfffe;
   public static readonly int WM_IPC = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_IPC");
   public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");
   [DllImport("user32")]
   public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]//, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
   [DllImport("user32")]
   public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
}
```

I've tried this with many permutation of using PostMessage, SendMessage, just using static int messages, actually invoking the RegisterWindowMessage.  Nothing seems to work.

Additionally, I would like to not just be able to specify a specific message, but also additional dynamic details like a username and some message text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

You are sending message HWND_IPC (window handle?) instead of WM_IPC. 
HWND_IPC is with value 0xFFFE not in the range for user messages WM_USER+x.

You cannot transfer data in this way. There is a WM_COPYDATA which copies
the given buffer from one processes private address space to that of the other...

I think you should use a named pipe to transfer data. 
SendMessage is so Win31 ;-)

Comment: I'm hoping I can circumvent the whole issue of writing a pipeserver.  I think I should be able to in two or so very short methods accomplish this with native window messaging.

Comment: I think the Named pipes solution is the most convenient: You set up a "server" stream and wait for some "client" to connect. Then you transfer the data just as you would through any other stream.

Here's NamedPipeServerStream: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx
And this is NamedPipeClientStream : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx
The code example there pretty much covers it.

Comment: Checking it out as we speak.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

I thought you'll need the override, although I am not sure it exists in a WPF view:

try this:

```
protected override void WndProc( etc...
```

[UPDATE]
You cannot override WndProc in the Window class of WPF this way.

[How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)

Will explain that you'll need a hook:

```
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }
```

Putting this together:

In your App.xml.cs you'll initialize your App startup arguments. It's easiest to create some static properties. Keep them simple, no collections to avoid multithreading collapses later on:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string SomeValue { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        SomeValue = e.Args[0];
    }
}
```

Now you are able to access `SomeValue` throughout your code by just calling `App.SomeValue`.

Then; a WndProc has to be implemented into a window. A window has a message pump. Without the a message pump you just can't send messages (you could create your own, but that's too much)

So in a window, for example MainWindow, implement the override:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    public IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, 
                          IntPtr wParam, IntPtr iParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == NativeMethods.HWND_IPC)
            MessageBox.Show("Message Received!");

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

internal class NativeMethods
{

etc. etc.
```

The only thing left to implement is the moment to fire the message, but since it is IPC, you basically could send it from anywhere, provided you have a handle to the target window.

Combine this info with Franks remarks about WM_COPYDATA and it is ready to go. For info on WM_COPYDATA:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Doesn't that override have parameters like "`ref Message message`"?  I am targetting framework 4, so I don't think I can use type `Message`.

Comment: Thanks, just looked at the update.  I tried something very similar to this previously, but the problem was the the WndProc was in my MainWindow class.  Which whenever I would try to access through App.xaml.cs I would get "Object unused" exceptions.

Comment: I cannot get it to compile.  I am still using the App.xaml StartUp event handler, though.  I see nothing for SourceInitialization.

Comment: But will that not neuter my ability to handle command line parameters when my application is started in that way?  I thought I could only get the necessary e.Args array when I handled the OnStartUp directly in App.xaml at the top level.