# Open window designed in WPF from external exe and receive return values from methods

Tags: c#, wpf, com

Is there some `"new/better"` way to open a `WPF window` and get some return object when it closes than using `COM`?

Or is it still - in year 2014 - the way to go?

Something like this:

```
[Guid("14B55D90-E07B-4DC9-B2EE-25F15607518B")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ComInterface
{
    [DispId(0)]
    void ShowWindow();
}

[Guid("CC01974D-82E2-4E9E-A48C-562D3ED83459")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ComInterface))]

public class ComClass: ComInterface
{
    public void ShowWindow()
    {
        MainWPFWindow window = new MainWPFWindow();
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx) for example. Depends on what the "external exe" is.

Comment: @floele The other exe would be a second wpf application and a excel/word addin.

Comment: Well, from a second WPF application you can just reference the other DLL and call whatever classes you like? If the addin is also developed using .NET you can do the same. So why even consider COM?

Comment: @floele I cannot reference to a DLL i need to be able to tell a running exe to open a window and get some values that this instance of the application already holds.

Comment: OK then we are talking about inter process communication. There are many options... .NET remoting, Windows messages, named pipes, etc. If you just want to tell another app to open a Window, a simple SendMessage() will suffice though.

Comment: @floele could you provide some links? For the topics you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are apparently looking for is *inter-process communication*. With .NET, you have various options, among the following:

- [Windows messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (it boils down to [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [handling these in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf), or [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you need to transfer more data than just integers)
- [Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)
- [.NET remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example)
- Other libraries built on top of these like [XDMessaging](http://thecodeking.github.io/XDMessaging.Net/Usage.html)

Here is another list for IPC methods: [Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it, if its what I need I gona accept your answer for now a +1 must be enough. :)