# Want to get input from Keyboard using windows api's

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, window, user32

I want to get the  keyboard input (single) using windows api's

i have two found  option
1.  `keybd_event() of user32.dll`

```
VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  _In_  BYTE bVk,
  _In_  BYTE bScan,
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

2   SendInput() of user32.dll

```
UINT WINAPI SendInput(
  _In_  UINT nInputs,
  _In_  LPINPUT pInputs,
  _In_  int cbSize
);
```

i want to import them in my WPF app  which one should i go after ??

Comment: Those functions generate input event messages. Is that what you want? It doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Oo ..ok @David ...And yes i don't want that ... i just want to take input from key board by using the native api's

Comment: Please can you fix the question to make it 100% clear what you want. Please remove mention of these two unrelated functions. Please also explain why you can't use the standard built in WPF facilities to receive input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives.

## RegisterHotKey

```
// Registers a hot key with Windows.
[DllImport(“user32.dll”)]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
// Unregisters the hot key with Windows.
[DllImport(“user32.dll”)]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

Since you are targeting WPF you would also need to add a WndProc to your `HwndSource`.

More information in this question: [How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)

## SetWindowsHookEx

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
```

More information from PInvoke.net: [SetWindowsHookEx (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowsHookEx)

Comment: icame across this `delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);` every thing is ok but what are the parameters that it is taking(// i know there types but what are the values that i should pass) code=? wParam=? lParam=?

Comment: @AVIKDUTTA The arguments are filled in automatically by the Windows message pump / Queue. You would need to read about how WndProc works here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx