# Change 1px border color to custom color instead of accent color in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

Windows 10 draws this 1px border in the accent color around most windows including the window of our WPF app or as seen here `cmd.exe`:
[image: 1px accent color]

But Visual Studio (which is also WPF) has changed that to fit its status bar color:
[image: 1px VS]

We would like to do the same, but I found nothing on how we can do this for WPF.
Does anybody know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to add a [window proc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf) to your window and handle the WM_NCPAINT message. This is similar to what's done in this code project article: [Class for drawing a flat color border](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/16616/class-for-drawing-a-flat-color-border) though he's doing it on child controls, the principle is the same for top-level windows.