# C# .NET WPF Window Mousedown/Keydown does not fire for the 4-color Buttons off TV Remote connected via USB Infrared receiver

Tags: c#, .net, television, infrared

I know my question title is hard to understand.

But simply put I purchased a remote off ebay, it's a standard TV remote but comes with a USB IR Receiver. When connected it can control the mouse cursor by pointing at the receiver. Also pressing most of the buttons appear to map to some keyboard key. Except for 4 buttons that I want to make use of - 4 color keys.

So most modern day remotes has these 4 color keys, red, green, yellow and blue.

For some reason pressing them does not cause the KeyDown event to fire at all.

So I'm wondering if anyone who's done something similar know how to capture these signals in a .NET desktop app, and be able to respond to these pressed keys?

Comment: I’m not sure how anyone could answer this - you haven’t even included the model number of the device in question.

Comment: Use Winspector to track the WM_ events fired when you push those buttons, [handle those specific events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf).

Comment: @theMayer It's a generic remote, so no brand or model number for that fact, it's called 2.4ghz Air Mouse & Keyboard. On that note, I noticed that do have a table that maps what the Windows equivalent is for each key, but the 4 color keys are stated as IR Learning keys, hmmm not sure what that means

Comment: @IanKemp I sort of tried that, I hooked into WndProc to inspect every message but it looks like pressing those 4 buttons yields no windows message.

Comment: Following webpage has lots of good info : http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy

Comment: IR Learning key means it can be used to copy the IR signal from another infrared remote controller and generate the same IR signal when you press it. That is, you cannot capture the key press from your 2.4G RF receiver plugged in your USB port. Instead, it is the IR receiver on your TV that will receive and process the signal.